# Is it possible to install Time::Stamp module in ActivePerl 5.8.8 build 820

Tags: perl

Is it possible to install the Time::Stamp module in ActivePerl 5.8.8 build 820?
I get a 401 authorisation error when I try to install the package via ppm.

Regards, john.tm

Comment: The 401 is coming from the server from which you're trying to retrieve the package.  Resolve that first, or try a different server, or use CPAN instead.

Comment: ActiveState gives free access to the PPM repositories of their 2 most recent releases.  For anything crustier than that you'll need to pay for support.  5.8 is the crustiest version they support...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pay for support the only way I know to install anything in a version that old is to use cpan.

```
cpan Time::Stamp
```

Comment: He's unlikely to have a compiler installed, and he's unlikely to have a version of the tools that automatically install a compiler, so that's unlikely to work without creating a proper environment first.